# Set Value of CSS Property when CSS is string in C#

Tags: c#, css, parsing

I have a string in C# that's essentially a CSS file. I can parse this CSS file and extract values with this library that has been extremely helpful: https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS

That's all fantastic. However, I now need to change the values within the file and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to reliably do this.

In the simplest terms possible, I have this string in C#:

```
body
{
   background-color:#323432;
}
```

I need to write a function:

```
public string ChangeValue(string oldstring, string name, string type, string value)
```

That when called with this:

```
string newstring = ChangeValue("body{background-color:#323432;}", "body","background-color","#ffffff");
```

The "newstring" string above, turns into this:

```
body
{
   background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Really really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `public string ChangeValue` or are you stuck with a `void` return type?

Comment: You need algorithm how to parse css string? Do array from this using '}', than '{', than subarray using ';'. Or I does not understand your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this without passing in the old `string`. You'll need to return a `string`, not `void`.

```
public static string ChangeValue(string name, string type, string value) {
     return String.Format("{0}\r\n{{\r\n    {1}:{2};\r\n}}", name, type, value);
}
```

output:

```
body
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

---

But why not use the API the ExCSS exposes?

```
var parser = new Parser();
var stylesheet = parser.Parse(css);

var bodyBackgroundColor = stylesheet.StyleRules
  .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Selector.ToString() == "body")
  .Declarations
  .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "background-color")
  .Term = new HtmlColor(255, 255, 255);

Console.WriteLine(stylesheet.ToString(true, 0));
```

Output:

```
body{
        background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, how did you figure out that the API exposes that ability?

Comment: I guessed when I saw this exposed in the public API https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS/blob/master/ExCSS/IToString.cs